# Swift base64 not ok

Tags: swift, base64, vapor

I'm using the Vapor framework to download a PDF file :

```
    let logpw = "myLogin:passWord"
    let url = "https://someRESTsite/invoices/1.pdf"
    let utf8str = logpw.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString()

    let response = try drop.client.get(url, headers:["Authorization":"Basic " + base64Encoded!])
```

this works fine. Note that I'm base64 encoding the login/pw for basic auth and this works for logging in and getting the file. Now I have to embed that PDF into an XML file in base64 using similar code:

```
if let bodyBytes = response.body.bytes {

    let bodyByteString = try String(bytes: bodyBytes)
    let utf8String = bodyByteString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64String = utf8String?.base64EncodedString()
}
```

the result is a string that actually really looks like a base64 string, but it's different than converting the same PDF using an online tool (I tried 2 which gave the same result).

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you know what format the PDF arrives in? Perhaps it’s already in base64?

Comment: It's not in base64, when downloading it with a browser it's just a PDF file. When downloading it in my app and eg print(response.body) it looks like: - Body:
 %PDF-1.6
%

1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
/ViewerPreferences <</PrintScaling /None>>...